# In Tkinter which event I should use for Lan Socket values

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, window, lan

Like I'm sending some data through LAN socket then My event should activate and use data I sent.

Comment: so, to clarify,  when the code is run, if the user does not submit the correct credentials, then the window will remain open even if the program is shutdown with the task manager ?

Comment: Yes If credentials are correct window will close else will stay as is.
And as window is Always ON top and Full screen it will not be easy to close it through task manager, byt yes Thats the main Issue It should not be closed by any meanse.

Comment: interesting.  do you have any basic minimal code that you have tried so far ?

Comment: full screen : root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
for always ON TOP : root.attributes('-topmost',True)
I used this two lines next I'm stuck :(